# Check if a distribution is discrete or continuous from the characteristic function of the distrution?

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

Is it possible to check if a distribution is discrete or continuous from the characteristic function/Laplace transform of a distribution?

Comment: If the characteristic function is integrable, then the distribution is absolutely continuous by the inversion formula for characteristic functions.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Can you provide a reference for the same?

Comment: See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Inversion_formulas).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That answers my question.